# Make A Local Admin Account On Domain Computer

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, administrator, domain, local

I want to know if it is possible to make a local admin account on a domain computer. I know that there is already an account called 'Admin' which is local but I want to make another one because I forgot the password. I already have an 'Admin' account on the **domain** but it doesn't let me run admin programs on the computer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have administrative rights over the computer then you should be able to reset the password using **net user** command

Comment: Did you ask your IT department?

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to create another 'Admin' account, you would need to do it from an administrator account on the local computer. You cannot create an admin account from a standard account(unless you have the administrator login). If you have forgot your password, contact your network administrator.

If you do have an admin account, please refer to [this](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-2012/create-local-administrator-on-windows-server-2012-r2.html#opt2) guide.